# mod_deflate enabled for amf?

Tags: apache-2.2, compression, coldfusion

coldfusion 8,
apache 2.2

running locally on XP pro. sp 3

--

Im trying to get mod_deflate working for amf. I've seen acouple of post that mention this is possible. But I cannot seem to get it to work for myself.

eg. http://wadearnold.com/blog/flash/gzip-compression-is-not-part-of-amf

the compression is working for other minetypes I've added to the AddOutputFilterByType so the deflate is working correctly.

ive tried the following minetypes; application/x-amf, application-x/amf, application/amf.
tho application/x-amf should be the one.

Basically just added the minetype to AddOutputFilterByType thats all?
Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found your answer, but I just posted a solution to a similar problem on my blog yesterday - it may or may not work for you as I'm not familiar with AMF: [Forcing Apache's mod_deflate module to compress JSP's from Weblogic](http://www.sysadminsjourney.com/content/2009/08/06/forcing-apaches-moddeflate-module-compress-jsps-weblogic)

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

That link explicitly says it (almost certainly) isn't possible, for pure protocol reasons alone.

Also the apache compression modules only compress output from static files, not other modules (without a bit of extra work).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think the link explicitly says it isn't default part of AMF, anyway I got it working with Apache and mod_deflate.

This was actually more to test it as there was more info on Apache then ISS, now i need it to get working on a IIS server and after some struggle I got it working with IIS 5.1 only with 3rd party software and only on IIS 5.1, not 6.0 what our production server is. arrgg getting closer tho.